# Sequence of simple functions

Tags: real-analysis

Can someone please help me to find a sequence of simple functions defined in the interval $[0,1]$, that converges pointwise to $f(x)=x$ in $[0,1]$?

Answer (score 2):

A simple function is just a "step function" with finitely many steps, or better, a finite sum of [indicator functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indicator_function).

A crude approximation of $f(x) = x$ by an indicator function would be $f_0(x) := 0$.

A better one is
\begin{align}
f_1(x) := 
\begin{cases}
0 & \text{ if } 0 \leq x < \frac12,
\\
\frac12 & \text{ if } \frac12 \leq x \leq 1
\end{cases}
\end{align}

Get the idea?

In general, you could say something like $f_n(x) := $ "write $x$ in binary and truncate after $n$ digits" or formalize like [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1160858/a-sequence-of-simple-functions-converges-uniformly-to-f?rq=1).

Comment: i think i got it

Comment: A simple function need not be a step function.